# Error installing fastthread 1.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

On Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite

#### RVM

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.26.10 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

#### Ruby

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

 * ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

#### Issue

```
$ gem install fastthread -v '1.0.7'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fastthread:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150217-53934-1vamxar.rb extconf.rb
extconf.rb:13: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

make  clean
Makefile:81: *** missing separator.  Stop.

make
Makefile:81: *** missing separator.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/fastthread-1.0.7/gem_make.out
```

Any help or pointer is most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fastthread` only works on MRI. It replaces/hooks into the private internal implementation details of MRI's green threads implementation. It does not work on any other Ruby implementation. In particular, it won't work on YARV, which you are using, because YARV has a completely different threading implementation based on native OS threads, not green threads.

Note that maintenance on MRI ended on July 31st, 2014. You *really* shouldn't be using MRI anymore. Plus, MRI only implements Ruby 1.8, whose maintenance *also* ended July 31st, 2014.

Comment: Makes sense. I am trying to upgrade a Rails project to use a more recent version of ruby, ultimately 2.2.0. I can't remember why I had this gem in my `Gemfile`, I may be able to live without it (?). I will comment it out for starter.